# Angular range slider jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, plugins, slider

I've been using this great slider on an Angular application http://refreshless.com/nouislider/download

Really like this slider as it's tiny compared to the jQuery UI Slider and has built in touch controls. It really is very nice.

So I created a directive which filters a data list and works well. What I need know though is a way to change the range values on the fly. So as data comes in, I get a new low and/or high value and update the range.

Here is a quick, basic Plunker of the directive I am using

**http://plnkr.co/edit/VH2WvyJMsLSTpWJawT2f?p=preview**

So not sure if this is an Angular thing, or a plugin thing. Could possibly instantiate the directive whenever I get a new value?

So would like to hear your thoughts.

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to have the range of your slider as scope variable of your directive. Then listen for any changes that occur on this variable and update the slider.

This can be achieved with the following :

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    values: '=ngModel',
    boundaries : '=' // the range of the slider
  },
```

and then the part where you listen for changes :

```
scope.$watch('boundaries', function(oldVal, newVal) {
  if(scope.slider !== null) {
    remove();
  }
  create();
});
```

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GrKfjhKomvYM70o4PzJR?p=preview)

PS : Unfortunately there is no easy way to update the range of the noUiSlider. That's why I end up creating an inner div inside diretive's element.

Comment: Sorry to jump in here. This directive you've written is great, any chance you can expand it to work with the "handles" option? I've tried to add it in by adding in "handles: scope.handles", but i'm not sure about the logic that is happenin in the change function.

Comment: @flashpunk The plunker have been updated to accommodate the handles attribute. Hope it will help